# In Dask Array, is there any difference between a block and a chunk?

Tags: python, dask

In Dask Array, is there any difference between a block and a chunk?

In the docs it seems like the two are used synonymously. E.g. [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-chunks.html#specifying-chunk-shapes) (at list item #3 they say block instead of chunk) or [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-chunks.html#chunks-examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chunks are basically the same thing as blocks for arrays. But chunk in this context is more like an action: to cut the whole dataset into chunks/blocks.

This action is also called partitioning in some contexts, particularly for dataframes and bags (which also have chunks, but they are not normally called blocks).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I just ran across a method called blocks, like two_dim_dask_array.blocks, that, when iterated, gives blocks of shape (row-size of the chunks, col-size of the whole array) that consist of chunks.
The print output of one iteration would be, e.g.: dask.array<blocks, shape=(800, 7000), dtype=int32, chunksize=(800, 700), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
So it seems to me like blocks are used to describe arrays of chunks?

Comment: @dkuers Yes, the method returns the blocks and you can call the `compute` function to compute these objects. Perhaps you can take a look at the documentation [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.Array.blocks)